# How to run my iPhone application once a while even the user doesn't open the app?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to do this?

Edit: Not even if I try to have an alarm after my application is closed for a short period of time??

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the short answer is no.

You can use the [Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to pop-up an alert to the user.  But they will still have to click on it to launch your app.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's a way if you jailbreak the phone.

Also, the latest OS has push notification.

In general, third-party apps don't run in th background. There have been some rumors that Apple might open this up a bit, if only to certain apps.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible on an un-jailbroken device.